# itext 7 PDFA1B conversion was successful, however Acrbat DC compaints "CIDSet in subset font is missing"

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm using itext 7 to convert a PDF file to PDF A-1B file.
itext 7 PDFA1B conversion was successful, however Acrobat DC complaints "CIDSet in subset font is missing"
Is there a way to fix this issue ?

This is how I do the conversion

```
PdfADocument pdf = new PdfADocument(writer,
                PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B,
                new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "https://www.color.org",
                        "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", new FileInputStream(PDFA1B_PROFILE_FILENAME)));
        pdf.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-au"));
```

Comment: *"I'm using itext 7 to convert a PDF file to PDF A-1B file."* - How do you *convert*? I only see your code creating a new PDF/A document.

Comment: PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("pdf_file.pdf"));
            int numberOfPages = srcDoc.getNumberOfPages();
            srcDoc.copyPagesTo(1, numberOfPages, pdfDoc);

Comment: I'm afraid copying pages alone does not convert, it copies non-PDF/A material into the new document making it non-PDF/A-conform, too.

Comment: Thanks mkl, any idea how to avoid/skip copying non-PDFA material ? or is there a way non PDF-A  pdf file to convert into PDF-A ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no built-in PDF-to-PDF/A conversion in iText. And in general that also is not easy to do: For example in case of fonts which would have to be embedded but are not available, or in case of already embedded fonts which do not provide information on which glyph corresponds to which character.

Comment: Thanks mkl, even I tried embedding fonts and had no luck with iText. Appreciate your time on responding to this thread.